# SharePoint Application Server is crashed and not booting

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007

SharePoint Application Server is crashed and not booting. Central admin is also not accessible. We have two webfront end servers but central admin is hosted only in application server.application is still working partially. So what to do ?

Shall we install SharePoint in totally new farm?

or

Shall we disconnect the corrupted server from farm and connect some new server in farm?

How to do that?

Comment: what is sharepoint version?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you have couple of options.

1. Build a new Server as App and then join it to existing farm with hosting central admin on it.Then Remove the old server from farm.Start the services on the App server and dns settings etc.
2. Disconnect the corrupted server from farm forcefully and host the central admin on one of the wfe. this will be quick as no new server required at the moment.start all the app server services here